# how to get data outside request

Tags: node.js, request

I have a scenario where i need to take response (body) of request method outside request. How can i do it?

```
request.post({
      url: 'http://localhost/api/messages',
      form: { key: message }
  }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
          tmsg = body;
      })
  console.log(tmsg);
```

I need this tmsg outside for next processing, Actual scenario is as below.

```
app.post('/incomemsg', function (req, res) {

  var mediaCount = req.body.NumMedia;

  if (mediaCount == 0) {
    //var twiml = getResponse(message);
      var twiml = new MessagingResponse();
      request.post({
          url: 'http://localhost:3978/api/messages',
          form: { key: message }
      }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
              tmsg = body;
          })
      console.log(tmsg);
  }else {
   //dosomething which outputs tmsg
}
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
  res.end(tmsg.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to assign value to a global variable in `request.post's` callback() which is only called after `request.post` is executed by Asynchronous logic(API calls are all async), so a better way would be to **promisify** request.post and await the request.post to make it seem synchronous.

```
const requestPromisified = requestObject =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(requestObject, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(body);
    });
  });

const body = await requestPromisified({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/api/messages",
  form: { key: message }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only can do something with tmsg when you made the request so you need to rearrange your code like this:

```
app.post('/incomemsg', function (req, res) {

    var mediaCount = req.body.NumMedia;
    var twiml = new MessagingResponse();

    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3978/api/messages',
        form: { key: message }
    }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        tmsg = body;
        console.log(tmsg);

        if (mediaCount === 0) {
            //do something with tmsg
        } else {
            //do something else with tmsg


        }

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
        res.end(tmsg.toString());
    });
});
```

Otherwise tmsg will be null because there was no request made to fill that variable.